# Posting code inside the post instead of in the template file using shortcode

Tags: plugins, php, functions, shortcode

I am using two plugins one of which is [Thumbs Rating](http://wordpress.org/plugins/thumbs-rating/) which have have a shortcode like this for example in order to display the thumbs rating option:

The code bellow is to be used in the templates files but I would like to have the option of using functions like the bellow and related ones inside posts using a shortcode if possible.

```
<?=function_exists('thumbs_rating_getlink') ? thumbs_rating_getlink() : ''?>
```

I add this into my post but it doesnt show instead gets parsed as normal text.

Is there a way to convert the code above into a shortcode something like [thumbsrating] which I can use in my posts. ( I want to paste the shortcode at a specific spot inside my post this is the reason for doing this )

Edit: Here is the code I had created with shortcode API but it didnt work:

```
    function rating_function() {
  return '=function_exists('thumbs_rating_getlink') ? thumbs_rating_getlink() : ''';
}
add_shortcode('rating', 'rating_function');
```

The result I got by adding the shortcode [rating] in my post was the return as text and not executed as PHP.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: It seems like you have not take a look to the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). Go there, read, try and come back if you need help.

Comment: I actually did try but since it didnt work, I thought it was a wrong approach. I have updated my post with the code I had used in functions.php. If you see any problems with it let me know please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your shortcode function with following code:

```
function rating_function() {
    if (function_exists('thumbs_rating_getlink')) {
        $content = thumbs_rating_getlink();
    }
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('rating', 'rating_function');
```

Comment: Thank you it works great, one thing I have is the output being displayed in the very top but that is another issue I am reading more about it right now, will update the comment soon.

Comment: Edited the answer to show also the possibility for anyone not getting the output in their desired spot but instead at the very beginning, I hope it helps someone in the future reading this.